# Python memory errors when hashing large number of files in sequence

Tags: python, memory, hash

Basically for practice/fun, I'm creating a list of all my files, hashing each file and searching against the list for duplicates. This is just for me; it doesn't matter how bad it is.

I keep getting the following error,

```
python(16563) malloc: *** mmap(size=140400698290176) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

The script is reading in a 22MB text file, and many of the files I'll be hashing are videos, generally but not always below 4GB. I'm not a good *programmer*; I usually design UI/UX, so memory, hardware, computation—this Jedi knows not these things.

I'm on a Mac (10.8.5); I have 32GB of RAM. Python is running in 64bit mode (2.7). There are 7 Volumes being scanned; my boot drive is the smallest, it's a 90GB SSD.

```
# This class mostly just calls os.stat and hashes the file
class FileInspection:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path
        self.hash = self.double_hash(path)
        self.inspectable = True
        stats = os.stat(path)
        self.size = stats.st_size
        self.last_mod = stats.st_mtime

    def double_hash(self, path):
        checksum = None
        matching_checksums = False
        match_attempts = 0
        while not matching_checksums:
            match_attempts += 1
            fileData = open(self.path).read()
            checksum1 = hashlib.md5(fileData).hexdigest()
            checksum2 = hashlib.md5(fileData).hexdigest()
            if checksum1 == checksum2:
                checksum = checksum1
                matching_checksums = True
            elif match_attempts > 3:
                self.hash = False
                self.inspectable = False
        return checksum


# This is the main function call
def masterList(self, path):
        f = open(path, "r")
        lines = f.readlines()
        f.close()

        f = open(path, "w")
        for line in lines:
            line = line[:-1]
            fileInfo = FileInspection(line)
            fileStr = 'f_{0} = {1}"checked":False, "path":"{2}", "inspectable":{3}, "hash":, "filesize":{4}, "lastmod":"{5}"{6}'.format(fileInfo.hash, "{", fileInfo.path, fileInfo.inspectable, fileInfo.hash, fileInfo.last_mod, "}")
            f.write(fileStr)
        f.close()

masterList("/path/to/a/giant/list/of/files.txt")
```

Comment: Are you on 32-bit or 64-bit Python?

Comment: How do I check? python -v doesn't provide this and I'm basically a nub w/ python

Comment: ``import sys; print(sys.maxint)``.

Comment: 64-bit, it turns out; well, I used `import platform` and  then `platform.architecture()`, which prints `64bit`

Comment: Why are you hashing the data twice and seeing if the results match?

Comment: Mostly to be paranoid. :) 225,000 files to check, and the goal is to delete duplicates, of which I am expecting ~25-30,000. Since I won't be checking any of these by hand, and I'm using the hash result as the sole metric, just decided to make damn sure it was error free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably running 32-bit python and trying to load more than 4 gb into the process. You can either try running the code in 64-bit python, or refactor the following md5 code in your double_hash function:

```
fileData = open(self.path).read()
checksum1 = hashlib.md5(fileData).hexdigest()
checksum2 = hashlib.md5(fileData).hexdigest() # Why calculate this twice?
```

to this:

```
read_size = 1024 # You can make this bigger
checksum1 = hashlib.md5()
with open(self.path, 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read(read_size)
    while data:
        checksum1.update(data)
        data = f.read(read_size)
checksum1 = checksum1.hexdigest()
#continue using checksum1
```

Generating the md5 this way will avoid loading the whole file into memory.

Comment: Well it's definitely 64-bit mode, but, I'm still appreciative of the advice; this is still reading the entire file size, yes?

Comment: Yes, it's still reading the entire file, but it only reads part of the file at a time. Are you sure it's 64-bit? I saw your comment above, and I think platform.architecture() just tells you the bitness of your OS. Try `import sys; print(sys.maxsize > 2**32)` If That's True then you're running 64-bit python.

Comment: Oh! Ok, thanks—when I run  the `sys.maxsize` comparison it returns true. So—64bit?

Comment: Oh yeah, then you probably are running 64 bit python. You're just using more memory than you have available then.

Comment: Well, in any case, this is working—thanks very much.

Comment: Oh wow, I'm not sure why then. I'm glad this worked for you though.